# Show googlemap for the selected country name from the dropdown list

Tags: php, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I have some countries name with states name in my dropdown list. Lets say I have 4 countries name (USA, India, SriLanka, China) and all these are in dropdown list. Now when I will click on any of the countryname then the map should show the selected country map. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? I am using [Gmap3 plugin](http://gmap3.net) to show google map. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274696/google-maps-api-3-search-box) should help you.

Comment: [Example that uses the Google Maps Javascript API v3 geocoder (but not the Gmap3 plugin) to zoom to countries with a dropdown list](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html)